# Media Query is not working properly

Tags: responsive-design

I've been trying to implement media query in simple html and css. But for some strange reasons it's not working. I've tried it with or without 'viewport' meta tag, different browsers, several breakpoints etc. Background color responses but the main problem is with the element's size(specially width). size doesn't (response) shrink as the browser window shrinks. I don't know what's wrong with this. am I missing anything? It'd be great help if somebody tell me what is the possible cause.

html:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Media Query Practice_2</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media_Query2.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="image/f1202536.jpg">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <h2 style="text-align:center;">
                    Hello
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mncontentWrapper">
                <div class="content_1 gap">
                    <p class="s">
                         The Atlantic was always moody and September storms had blown up from nowhere so that the great grey rollers had smashed constantly against the cliffs round Cape <a href="#Early">Trafalgar</a>. Today, however, the sea  has calm, with a soft north-westerley wind bringing up cloud that dropped a gauze veil long the coast.                   
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="content_2 gap">
                    <ol>
                        <li>Mango</li>
                        <li>Berry</li>
                        <li>Jack fruit</li>
                        <li>Banana</li>
                        <li>Lychee</li>
                        <li>Grape</li>
                        <li>Apple</li>
                        <li>Pineapple</li>
                        <li>Coconut</li>
                        <li>Avocado</li>

                    </ol>

                </div>
                <div class="content_3">
                    <p class="s">
                         The Atlantic was always moody and September storms had blown up from nowhere so that the great grey rollers had smashed constantly against the cliffs round Cape <a href="#Early">Trafalgar</a>. Today, however, the sea  has calm, with a soft north-westerley wind bringing up cloud that dropped a gauze veil long the coast.                   
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <h3 style="text-align:center;">Media Query</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`   
css code:
```

*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.wrapper{

```
width:1200px;
min-height:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
```

}

.header{

```
background-image:;
min-height:150px;
background-color:lightgreen;
width:;
background-size:;
```

}

.mncontentWrapper{

```
min-height:800px;
width:100%;
padding-left:px;
```

}

.content_1{

```
min-height:800px;
width:380px;
float:left;
background-color:AntiqueWhite;
```

}

```
.content_2{

min-height:800px;
width:380px;
float:left;
background-color:DarkCyan;
margin-left:;
}

.content_2 ol{
    margin-left:30px;
}

.content_3{

min-height:800px;
width:380px;
float:left;
background-color:Lavender;
margin-left:;
```

}

```
.gap{

margin-right:30px;
}

.footer{

clear:both;
min-height:50px;
background-color:LightSteelBlue;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 1199px){

    .content_1{

        width:31%;

    }

    .content_2{
        width:33%;

    }

    .content_3{
        width:31%;
    }

}
```

@media only screen and (max-width: 519px){

```
 .content_1{

        width:100%;
        margin:0;
    }

    .content_2{

        width:100%;
        margin:0;

    }

    .content_3{
        width:100%;

    }

    .footer{

        width:100%;
        clear:;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you are after?
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/GqwdQk

The HTML is exactly as you posted. The CSS is the same as well except that I added `max-width:100%;` to the .wrapper class, line 5 of the CSS.

Without this edit, the .wrapper div has a hard-coded width of 1200px and so it isn't scaling to fit narrow viewports.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I also figured it out(max-width), but I solved this with wrapper width in 'px' not in '%'. So your suggestion really helped me. Though now I'm  having problem with elements height regarding media query :) . Thanks again